# how to set a String with fixed length in grails constraints?

Tags: grails

I have this domain class

```
class Client {
  String idCard
  ...

  static constraints = {
    idCard size:16
    ...
  }
}
```

I created some test data in bootstrap.groovy file

But i get the following error message

```
Caused by IllegalArgumentException: Parameter for constraint [size] of property [idCard] of class [class ni.sb.Client] must be a of type [groovy.lang.IntRange]
```

I need this property to be a String and have a fixed length

I am following size constraints [documentation](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Constraints/size.html) with no success

Thanks, for your time

Comment: Have you tried using a range such as: idCard size:16..16 ?

Comment: after trying i get **Error executing bootstraps; nested exception is java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer**

Comment: @user615274 is it showing that `ClassCastException` is in the domain class? I think that this Exception is thrown elsewhere

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use

```
static constraints = {
    idCard maxSize:16, minSize: 16 // or simply use size: 16..16
    ...
}
```

This works for Strings and will affect the schema generation `VARCHAR(16)` (e.g. for MySQL)

Comment: That would allow strings shorter than 16 characters, it doesn't enforce a _fixed_ length.

Comment: I finally came to implement a custom validator, check for idCard size if it is equal to 16.